# How to automate Firebase FCM push notification sending Integration Tests

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, integration-testing, google-admin-sdk, system-testing

I have a process that runs in a Java Cloud Function and sends notifications to Firebase's FCM using the [Firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

I'm currently testing this with unit tests that mock FCM classes.

I'd like to add system-level tests that verify that the integration works correctly. Ideally, I'd like to execute the Cloud function and assert that FCM (or a mock service) receives a request with the expected content.

I've currently tried.

- **Mocking FCM**: Since the FCM client initializes with *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* it doesn't seem to be possible to provide credentials such that the client sends the request to a mock service.
- **Registering an Android Client and asserting on notification reception**: It is quite cumbersome to setup and in some cases can take multiple minutes causing flakeyness.
- [**Using Firebase Local Emulator Suite**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite): It doesn't appear to support FCM yet.

What would be the best way of doing this?